# How to copy and rename specific files from specific folders? (Batch Command Line, Windows 10)

Tags: batch-file, command-line, copy, batch-rename

In Directory E:, I have Folder A with subfolders Folder A1, A2, A3...

I want to select "recent" files from specific subfolders from Folder A and copy them into Folder B (which is also on Directory E:).

I have used the following logic of code to select the specific subfolders based on a .txt file and the specific recent files based on robocopy maxage.

```
set sourceFolder=E:\ ...
set targetFolder=E:\ ...

for /f "delims=" %%a in (folders.txt) DO (
  if exist %sourceFolder%\%%a (
    if exist %targetFolder% (
        robocopy %sourceFolder%\%%a %targetFolder%\%%a /maxage:2 >nul
```

My problem now is that I need to rename these specific files based on their original parent folder's name. Such that:

```
E:\FolderA\FolderA1\file23.txt
E:\FolderA\FolderA1\file37.txt
E:\FolderA\FolderA2\file44.txt
```

is copied and renamed such that I have:

```
E:\FolderB\FolderA1_file23.txt
E:\FolderB\FolderA1_file37.txt
E:\FolderB\FolderA2_file44.txt
```

The additional problem I have is that the batch file is called from a different directory. I have tried various ren, move, forfiles, pushd, etc logic [Edit: Not simultaneously with robocopy] but I either get the syntax wrong or I am unable to change my working directory. What can I do?

EDIT:

I've tried:

```
set sourceFolder=E:\sourceFolder
set targetFolder=E:\targetFolder
set finalFolder=E:\finalFolder

for /f "delims=" %%a in (folders.txt) DO (
  if exist %sourceFolder%\%%a (
    if exist %targetFolder% (
        robocopy %sourceFolder%\%%a %targetFolder%\%%a /maxage:2 >nul
        for %%B in (%targetFolder%\%%a\*) do (
            echo percentage a is: %%a
            echo percentage b is: %%B
            REM xcopy %%B %finalFolder%\%%a_%%B*
    ))))
```

But the echo'd %%B prints as %targetFolder%\%%a\[filename] as opposed to just the [filename] so the rest doesn't work out.

Comment: You can't do that with Robocopy.  You would need to Iterate the files in each folder with another `FOR` command and then use `XCOPY` to copy and rename them on the fly.

Comment: @Squashman Sorry, I left out that detail. I edited in that I'm not trying to rename them simultaneously with robocopy - I learned that about it. I've tried renaming the files with separate commands (like on a line after the robocopy or elsewhere). Robocopy's maxage functionality is the best method I've found to select recent files so far, so that's why I've tried sticking with robocopy. I'd try xcopy, but I might keep the robocopy step which might be partially redundant in the copying process.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following which seem to work as intended:

```
set sourceFolder=E:\sourceFolder
set targetFolder=E:\targetFolder
set finalFolder=E:\finalFolder

for /f "delims=" %%a in (folders.txt) DO (
  if exist %sourceFolder%\%%a (
    if exist %targetFolder% (
        robocopy %sourceFolder%\%%a %targetFolder%\%%a /maxage:2 >nul
        pushd %targetFolder%\%%a
        echo we're at %cd% 
        for %%B in (*.*) do (
            xcopy %%B %finalFolder%\%%a_%%B*
        )
        popd
)))
```

Though this may not be a very efficient method, especially with an intermediate folder being involved.