# Robocopy with syntax variables to find files that are 'like'

Tags: syntax

How can I use *%computername%* where it can find files that are "like" instead of "exact"

robocopy \source\folder\ c:\destination *%computername%* /MIR /MOT:1

The above will find and copy all files that use the computer name in the name of the files. I need to find a way to find and copy any file that has something similar to the computer name. Example if source file is "02131924-5505" and the name of the computer is 'D5505'

Thanks you,
Mike

Not sure where to start

Comment: Your example is not completed, because you did not tell what replacement you want to have.... with which value do you want to replace the computer name?  Please do not let us guess, and provide enough information.

Comment: Maybe this: [How to copy and rename specific files from specific folders?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71227811/how-to-copy-and-rename-specific-files-from-specific-folders-batch-command-line) can help? (Or, in other words, what did you try to solve this problem yourself, like writing some batch file, or even powershell?)

Answer (score 0):

Tough call. You can substring the D5505 in a Windows batch file like

```
set cp4=%computername:~2,4%
```

then use that surrounded by wildcards, as in

```
robocopy \source\folder\ c:\destination *%cp4%*.* /MIR /MOT:1
```

but I'm not sure whether that makes you completely happy...